# Oscurecer fondo con jquery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

El problema que tengo es que quiero que mi web al darle al botón de búsqueda o a la lupa que me salga un input para poder buscarlo que quiero. Hasta ahí bien y creo que mas o menos lo tengo pero lo que quiero es que cuando le de click y me salga el input que toda la pagina se oscurezca menos el input... Como si fuera un modal o algo asi.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora. Y bueno stackoverflow no me deja enviar la pregunta porque dice que tengo mucho código... :)  No se porque me pone eso jejee

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#botonBusqueda").click(function() {
    $("#modal").toggle();
    $("#modal > input").css("width", "115%");


});

});
```

```css
.fondo {
    background-image: url('../img/2545370.jpg');
    height: 172vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
}


/* NavBar*/

.navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 11%;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

form {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 40%;
    width: 160%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="../jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b909a3cc21.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="miJs/miJavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>EasyLinks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--NavBar -->
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="../pro/img/Icono.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            </a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonBusqueda">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <div id="modal" class="input-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>-->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--NavBar -->

    <!-- Slide -->
    <section class="foo-class">
        <div class="container-fluid fondo">
            <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100 align-items-center">
                <h1>All is connected!</h1>
                <h6>Llega a cualquier sitio del mundo con unos sencillos clicks!</h6>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Navega</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: acabo de cambiar un poco el jquery con el toggle con algo mas practica para mostrar el input...

Comment: Bootstrap tiene una clase "modal-backdrop" que es la que se usa para oscurecer el fondo cuando se muestra una ventana modal. Si creas un div a primer nivel del body, y le pones/quitas esa clase consigues que aparezca/desaparezca el sombreado. Aquí tienes una forma de conseguirlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487052/how-to-activate-the-bootstrap-modal-backdrop

Comment: voy a mirarlo , pero eso me sirve para mi boton de busqueda?

Comment: Podrias probar metiendo el boton dentro de un modal y de esta manera vas apoder realizar lo que deseas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es:
Colocar dicho input en un modal respectivamente ya que e visto que usas boostrap.
o lo otro es un poco mas  complejo pero te permite hacerlo como tu quieras.

Define una Clase  o atributo id   en la etiqueta  
Luego  en la Funcion Jquery  al mostrar el Input  con el toggle pon antes de eso  el fundo oscuro  y opacidad 100%  Luego muestra el input en la parte de la pantalla que desees.

esto mismo lo podrías lograr también con un evento "focus".

Saludos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos dar respuestas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. Por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega el código que propones. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y la sección [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que entiendas de lo que hablo.

Comment: Entiendo lo del modal. Pero la otra forma que me has dicho no la acabo de pillar podrias poner un pequeño ejemplo?

Comment: Ejemplo,  en la función de Js  solo  tienes que ponerte a jugar con  css es decir: por ejemplo, puedes empezar a modificar el css para  que  al hacer click en  el  input se cambien los  stilos    y  se oscurezca el fondo y  el  input se muestre en otra pusicion de la pantalla. disculpa pero estoy desde el movil no puedo agregar codigo

Comment: bueno, la verdad esque no me voy a complicar la vida . Lo estoy haciendo con un modal y ya. Lo que estoy intentando ahora es cuadrarlo en el sitio que yo quiero.Puedo poner el modal donde yo quiera no? es que es mi primera vez con bootstrap y con Jquery y creo que se nota jaja.  Muchas gracias @JJMADEO

Comment: si, pero ciertamente  podrías dejarlo en el medio,   queda bien en el medio. aparte  el ya se encarga de todo y queda lindo.
o también podrías dejarlo en el medio y  poner en el modal el input  de búsqueda y abajo el resultado en tiempo real.

Comment: Ostras, ahora que lo dices ... Me parece una muy buena idea! Lo ultimo que me faltaría por preguntarte son dos cositas... :) En el modal como puedo quitar la cruz que hay arriba a la derecha para salir y que me salga directamente del modal cuando aprete en cualquier lado?.

Comment: La ultima es lo de los resultados en tiempo real se hace con Ajax no?

Comment: Con respecto a lo de cerrar el modal, hay una etiqueta o clase, no me acuerdo bien, que genera ese botón ahí arriba, es de boostrap,

Comment: @ZakariaNajimi  si se hace con ajax yo lo hacía de la siguiente manera, descargaba una vez todo lo qué hay para buscar a un array de tipo objeto json y usas alguna función que te permita buscar en el array completo, y con eso tienes una búsqueda veloz.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JJMADEO voy a probarlo.